# Regex not supported on snowflake

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, posix

I'm trying to extract from snowflake with the below regex:

`regexp_substr(col1,'(?<=Sample[^;]?=)(\\d*)(?=;)'),`

but it fails with:

> Invalid regular expression: no argument for repetition operator: ?

What would an equivalent expression be to make snowflake extract?

Comment: You really need to provide sample input and the watch output, for both good input, and bad (to not be matched) input.

Answer (score 1):

So the first positive look behind is wanting ?? (not 100%) "Sample and then not semicolon" then capture "zero or more digits" and then "semicolon"

```
SELECT 'Sample 123;' as col1
    ,regexp_substr(col1,'Sample[^;](\\d*);',1,1,'e')
;
```

Anyways the `'e'` says to turn on `extract sub-matches` and the other two parameters are where to start, and which match `occurance` to return.
Thus you lookahead and lookbehinds can just be written normally, and this gives `123` as the answer.

but I also think perhaps you are wanting:

```
SELECT column1 as col1
    ,regexp_substr(col1,'Sample[^;]?=(\\d*);',1,1,'e')
FROM VALUES 
    ('Sample=123;')  -- match, return 123
    ,('Sample =123;') -- match, return 123
    ,('Sample  =123;') -- no match, return NULL
;
```

which gives:

| COL1 | REGEXP_SUBSTR(COL1,'SAMPLE[^;]?=(\D*);',1,1,'E') |
| --- | --- |
| Sample=123; | 123 |
| Sample =123; | 123 |
| Sample =123; | NULL |